# Как сделать JOIN с условием?

Tags: sql

СУБД: MySQL 8.0.29

Есть таблица пользователей:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( id INT, country varchar(255) );
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `country`) VALUES
(1, "German"), (2, "USA"), (3, "France");
SELECT * FROM users;
```

Есть таблица зон влияния:

```
CREATE TABLE `influence-zone` ( id INT, name varchar(255), country varchar(255) );
INSERT INTO `influence-zone` (`id`, `name`, `country`) VALUES
(1, "zone", "German"), (2, "important", "USA"), (3, "zone89", "France"),
(4,"zone1", "ALL"), (5,"zone2", "ALL");
SELECT * FROM `influence-zone`;
```

Необходимо соотнести зоны влияния с пользователями, по стране.

Делаю так и решаю часть задачи:

```
SELECT * FROM `influence-zone` JOIN users ON `influence-zone`.country = users.country
```

Но остается две зоны (id: 4,5), со страной ALL.

Их нужно в выборке соотнести со всеми пользователями. Как это сделать одним запросом?

[Минимальный пример.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8db41cd9004c389441f474c56bf267df)

Comment: ON `influence-zone`.country = users.country OR `influence-zone`.country = "ALL"

Comment: ```ON influence-zone.country IN (users.country, "ALL")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно поняла

```
SELECT
 *
FROM `influence-zone`
JOIN users ON `influence-zone`.country = users.country
WHERE `influence-zone`.country <> "ALL"
union all 
SELECT
 *
FROM `influence-zone`
CROSS JOIN users
WHERE `influence-zone`.country = "ALL"
```

[Либо вот тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b75d42b00e9e7b95c73146125974b2da)

Но данным соединением мы создаем декартово произведение, что при наличии большого количества данных может нагрузить сервер.
Так что применять с аккуратностью.

P.S. Решение в комментариях (от @Akina) считаю гораздо лаконичнее и лучше.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM `influence-zone`
JOIN users ON `influence-zone`.country IN (users.country, "ALL")
```

[Посмотреть можете тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fbfb87a374a96701a0b1ace6cade118e)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]